# Get List of Pair of matching objects from two separate lists of objects using java 8 streams

Tags: java, algorithm, join, java-8, inner-join

I have one requirement where I want pair of matching objects on some condition from two Objects

For Ex:

```
Company{
id;
companyName:
address;
}

Employee {
id;
companyId;
name;
dob;
address;
}
```

So from above two objects I want `List<Pair<Company, Employee> > where company.id = employee.id;`

**Raw implementation:**

```
List<Pair<Company, Employee> > companyEmpPairList = companyList.stream().filter(company -> empList.stream().filter(company.id == emp.compId).findAny()).collect.toMap(company, employee)
```

Pair is Apache Class or any equivalent is fine for me.

Output should be something like:

```
List[Pair(c1, e1), Pair(c2,e2), Pair(c3,e3)...]
```

Comment: An efficient implementation of this is unlikely to be possible with streams, but will probably need to involve separate data structures with maps.

Comment: You're basically looking for JOIN (more specifically an INNER JOIN) algorithms as used in database systems. [Here](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.11.0.1/dbusage_en11/join-methods-optimizer-queryopt.html) (see list of algorithms on the left-hand side in the tree view) are some of the basic JOINS and ideas on how to join outlined. It shouldn't be too hard to implement e.g. a Hash-Join using `HashMap<>`.

Comment: @Mushroomator I am fine with HashMap or other object having these two elements. Do you have any idea to achieve this

Comment: Is it guaranteed that every `Employee.companyId` exists among provided companies?

Comment: Might be case where not exist

Comment: Then should such employees be present among pairs list?

Answer (score 1):

You can group employees by `companyId` and then build a pairs with the stream API:

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> employeesByCompanyId = employees.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getCompanyId));

List<Pair<Company, Employee>> pairs = companies.stream().flatMap(company ->
        employeesByCompanyId.getOrDefault(company.getId(), Collections.emptyList())
                .stream()
                .map(employee -> new Pair<>(company, employee))
).toList();
```

Comment: Thanks let me apply this in my use case

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is essentially a JOIN operation, more specifically an INNER JOIN, i. e. the intersection of two sets `A` and `B`.

There are many algorithms to perform these operations as these are the bread and butter of (relational) database systems.

[Here](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.11.0.1/dbusage_en11/hash-optimizer-queryopt.html) you find some high-level overview over some of the algorithms used (some of which I list here):

- Hash-Join
- Recursive-Hash-Join
- Merge-Join
- Nested-Loop-Join
- Sorted-Merge-join
- many more...

#### Example: Hash-Join

To give you a working example I've implemented a very basic generic implementation of a hash join (an INNER JOIN is performed). This version is far from perfect in terms of performance/ memory consumption etc. but I think it outlines the general idea and it is flexible enough to be re-usable for other joins you might wanna perform.

The idea is simple:
You build a lookup table of one of the two data sets you are comparing (ideally the smaller one, but I've skipped that here). Then loop over the other set and see if the keys within the lookup table match those in your second set. If they do add them to the result. If they don't, continue.
Last but not least, return the result set.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {

    public static class Pair<T, U>{
        T x;
        U y;
        public Pair(T x, U y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pair{" +
                    "x=" + x +
                    ", y=" + y +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    record Employee(String id, String companyId){};
    record Company(String id){};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var employees = List.of(
                new Employee("1", "A"),
                new Employee("2", "B")
        );
        var companies = List.of(
                new Company("A"),
                new Company("B")
        );

        var resultSet = hashInnerJoin(companies, employees, company -> company.id, employee -> employee.companyId);
        for (var pair: resultSet) {
            System.out.println(pair);
        }
    }

    public static <T, U, V> Iterable<Pair<T, U>> hashInnerJoin(Iterable<T> setA, Iterable<U> setB, Function<T, V> joinSetAOn, Function<U, V> joinSetBOn) {
        var lookup = buildLookup(setA, joinSetAOn);
        var result = new ArrayList<Pair<T, U>>();
        setB.forEach(x -> {
            var correspondingValue = lookup.get(joinSetBOn.apply(x));
            if(correspondingValue != null){
                result.add(new Pair<T, U>(correspondingValue, x));
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> buildLookup(Iterable<V> input, Function<V, K> keySelector){
        var hashMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
        input.forEach(x -> hashMap.put(keySelector.apply(x), x));
        return hashMap;
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
Pair{x=Company[id=A], y=Employee[id=1, companyId=A]}
Pair{x=Company[id=B], y=Employee[id=2, companyId=B]}
```

> **Remark**: One simple addition to this implementation would be to add an argument of `BiFunction<T, U, W>` which you can use to build the result value `W` which you call when you've found a "match" to include in the result. It takes the two matching objects of type `T` and `U` and builds a new result value of type `W`. Currently, for simplicity I am using the `Pair<T, U>` as a result value, but that would be an improvement.

#### See also

C# has a built-in function [`Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-7.0) which can be used on `IEnumerable<T>`s (essentially the equivalent to `Iterable<T>` in Java) which is production-ready, so you can have a look at the [C# implementation of this functionality on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L677). The idea is however exactly what I've been showing here.